# Quantity of Orzo when using other ingredients

Tags: pasta

I am making an orzo salad, and I am adding Rotisserie chicken, green onions, cherub tomatoes artichoke hearts, lemon juice and zest as well as herbs. I am making this for a BBQ party with apprx. 25 guests and am not sure how much orzo to cook. Can anyone give me an idea. I want the ingredients to be evenly matched, not heavy on one over another. Thank you for any answers.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about barley or the rice shaped pasta? Also, when you say you want the ingredients evenly matched, I'm thinking you mean 50% orzo and 50% other evenly matched ingredients. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you're asking. Without even knowing your location, it's difficult to be sure. With a location, we might be able to make a guess. We need more information to be able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience orzo behave much like rice, in the sense that grow a lot in volume after cooking.

I'm supposing that the orzo salad will be an apetizer or at least not a main dish, and you are talking about pearl barley which requires only 20-25 minutes of cooking with no pre-soak(but remember to wash it before cooking), so you can count about 50g per person.

50g x 25 = 1.250Kg (which can be rounded up to 1.5Kg just to be safe in case someone want a second dish)

If I recall correctly for every cup of orzo you add at least a cup and a half of water, so you'll need at least ~3.50L of water for the cooking

Comment: What is pearl orzo? Why such a long cooking time?

Comment: @Cindy Thanks for pointing it out, I've edited my answer since I was referring to pearl barley, also known as "orzo" because is the more common form in which the cereal is sold. As for the cooking time, I don't really know, but I guess that, as other cereal, is somewhat tough so it need more time to be ready.